# C++ boost library local_time_period

Tags: c++, boost

Using `#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"` its possible to get the current local time. I made the function to get the local time:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime getTime(){
     return boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
}
```

this function is returning local time of `boost::posix_time::ptime` type.
Example return: `Date2017-Nov-05 07:58:36`

I want to get some beginning Date and end Date. Then using `boost::posix_time::time_period` I want to count period of beginning and end dates.

```
int main(){
boost::posix_time::ptime startDate = getTime();
boost::posix_time::ptime endDate;
string duration; 
cout << "start Date" <<  startDate << endl;

for(int i = 0; i <= 900000000; i++) {
    if(i == 900000000){
        endDate = getTime();
    }
}
cout << "End Date " << endDate << endl;
duration = to_simple_string(boost::posix_time::time_period(startDate,endDate).length());
cout << "Duration:  " << duration << endl;
}
```

The `endDate` is in `for` loop because its the simplest way for me to get it few seconds after `startDate`.

The `cout << "string Duration  " << duration << endl;` outputs values like for example: `Duration:  00:00:04`

How to make `boost::posix_time::time_period` to return only seconds, for example, if my `startDate` is `Date2017-Nov-05 10:00:00` and `endDate` is `Date2017-Nov-05 10:00:10` the function should return just `10`, only number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subtract two `ptime` objects you will get a `time_duration` object. This object has a `total_seconds()` method which will give you the total number of seconds.

Eg:

```
// startTime and endTime are ptime instances
time_duration d = endTime - startTime;
long secs = d.total_seconds();
```

See: [time_duration accessors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#time_duration_accessors).